# Maintaining different concurrency for different queues in Sidekiq?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asynchronous, sidekiq

How can multiple instances of a specific worker be prevented from being executed via sidekiq asynchronously, also, i do not want to stop other processess from being executed asynchronously at the same time. How do i deal with this ?
I do not want to restrict my concurrency for all type of workers/processes in sidekiq.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkout the [sidekiq-limit_fetch](https://github.com/brainopia/sidekiq-limit_fetch) gem, which you can use to limit the number of jobs that are executed in a particular queue.

You can create a new queue for the job that you want executing one at a time, and give it a limit of one. This way you'll still be able to submit jobs to queue, but guarantee only one of them will be executing at a given time.